# Actionscript: Position elements one after another automatically

Tags: actionscript

Is it possible to make Sprites position themselves one after another automatically.
Similar to `display:display-block` in CSS.

For example i'm adding Sprites to some parent in a row, the way they are in xml skin file and they are automatically position themselves next to each other.

Is there an event, which tells that a child were added to the parent?

I could implement some extended Sprite, to position pushed elements automatically, by calculating where the last element is located?

Why the hell Actionscipt doesn't have something like CSS in it? It's a pain in the ass to build UI inside it, compared to HTML...

Madness...

Comment: I see that Flex is supporting CSS. But i can't find a list of supported CSS properties.

Comment: Each component's reference in the help (the blue pages) will list the supported styles you can use for that component.

Comment: What's "madness" is probably to try and apply solutions from one platform to another, when they are as different as HTML and Flash. Regarding libs for layout in ActionScript projects that don't use Flex, I recommend http://somerandomdude.com/work/coordy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of "raw" ActionScript you should either search for an appropriate library or do it your self. ActionScript doesn't define any CSS like logic.

On the other hand Flex does, but you will not find any CSS that let you define layout. CSS is used to modify visual appearance of containers and components in Flex. Layout is usually done with the `layout` property of the container classes provided by Flex. For example yo can use a `Group` and set its layout property to an instance of `HorizontalLayout` or `VerticalLayout`. This will automatically position all child components of the group either in x or in y direction. In case of using Flex you cannot use sprites directly, but there are many components you can use. Maybe there is one for your purposes.

See the Flex API documentation. The [spark.components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/package-detail.html) package will be a good starting point.